# German visa while in UK for Pakistani Passport Holder

Tags: schengen, pakistani-citizens, schengen-visas

I'm travelling to UK for 6 months with Pakistani Passport. Can I apply for German Visa while in UK?

Answer (score 2):

It might possible provided you fulfil certain conditions but its highly discouraged. Apply from your country of permanent residence.

> To apply for a Schengen visa from the UK you must be a UK resident for at least three months. If this condition is not fulfilled, the Consulate of your country of preference will hardly take the application into consideration.

After 3 months of your stay you May apply, however

> Non-residents such as travelers and tourists who plan on staying in the UK for 3 months or less should be discouraged from applying for a Schengen visa from within the UK. Instead, they should apply in their home country so that the application is processed, chances of getting a positive answer become greater.

**[Source](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/apply-from-uk/)**

Also

> Please note that if you are not a resident in the United Kingdom you should apply at the German Embassy in your country of residence.

**[Source](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/germany-visa/uk/)**

Lastly, a very authentic source, [VFS Global](http://www.vfsglobal.com/germany/uk/tourist.html), states the following elibility

> Eligibility
>
> Applicant must at least meet the following criteria in order to be
> eligible to submit a Schengen visa application:
>
> 1.holding a valid passport/travel document
>
> **2.holding a valid UK residence permit. In case applicant holds a short stay visa, a C type visa (see example here), for the UK, then  applicant needs to apply for a Schengen visa from his/her residence country.**
>
> 3.applying for a short stay visa (Tourist: including Minors, Visitor Family/Friends, Business, EEA/EU and Swiss national family member or
> Airport Transit)

(The emphasis is mine)

This case does not fulfil eligibility requirement number 2